# How to make a shell script return 0 even after getting killed

Tags: bash, shell, kill

I have a scheduled shell script running in a distributed environment. There are some scenarios where the process might get killed by some other processes. But I need the process to return 0 even after the failure/killed. Is there anyway to implement it in bash?

Comment: Can you change how the script is called? I am thinking this should work. `( somescript.sh || true )`

Comment: I know this will work but I can't start the process using this command.

Comment: Maybe you can use `trap` to exit 0 on any signal? Sorry, I am just spit-balling.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the signal. Bash allows you to trap with the `trap` command, but if your script is being killed with `SIGKILL` (9), it is uninterruptible and untrappable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this may be a case for some sort of watchdog process similar to how keepalived tracks processes.

At the simplest, the command pidof might be your friend here.